# Call Asynctask execute with void and cursor as parameters

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wrote a Asynctask as

```
private class dboperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>
```

I am new to android and wrote by searching a lot in google but got struck on how to call the Async Task from another class with these parameters.

Code

```
private class dboperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>{


        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getstocks="Select " + st.column1 + " as _id, " + st.column3 + " From "+ st.tablename;
            a1=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(getstocks, null);


            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            if(a1.moveToNext())
            {
                displaystocks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            final poplist populatestocks=new poplist(getApplicationContext(),a1) ;
            popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }


    }
```

when I am calling this way it is giving me error "**Void cannot be resolved into variable**".

```
dboperation.execute(Void,Void,a1);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what you want exactly? you need cursor on whitch method?

Comment: I want to know how to write execute for Asynctask with mentioned parameters because as you see when I declare as **dboperation.execute(Void,Void,a1);**. it is throwing error

Comment: @Siva : `AsyncTask.execute(Params... params)` where `params` is parameters which you want to pass to `doInBackground` so to execute Task use  `dboperation.execute((Void)null);` or `dboperation.execute();`

Comment: Still not accepting giving error **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method execute(Void...) from the type AsyncTask<Void,Void,Cursor>**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In
    AsyncTask

- 1st param means the type you can pass to execute. Void means you can pass nothing

The class names in Java should start with upper-calse letter. Please rename it for better readability by others.

So proper call would be

```
new DbOperation().execute();
```

- 2nd param is a type of data you can publish calling publishProgress() from doInBackground(). You don't use publishProgress, so nothing to mention in this case.
- 3rd param meana s type that will be passed to onPostExecute(). To pass the Cursor to onPostExecute you must return it from doInBackground

  ```
  @Override
  protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {

      getstocks="Select " + st.column1 + " as _id, " + st.column3 + " From "+ st.tablename;
      return Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(getstocks, null);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not allowing me to declare as **dboperation.execute();** any wayout

Comment: Yes, that's because you called a class from lowercase letter, which is misleading. It started from a lowercase letter so I thought it was already an instance. In yout case, call new dboperation().execute();

Comment: That's perfect....now its working.. Can you please throw some focus on why it is not responding when used **lowercase**

Comment: @Sive it was responding, but you didn't call it properly. You had to **new dboperation().execute();**, not **dboperation.execute();** (if dboperation was not pointing to the instance but rather to a class).

Comment: Thank you very much... that done the trick.. actually I am new to java and android

Answer (score 1):

```
   AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

asynkTask class get three parameter. first parameter used for `doInBackground` , if you want send one parameter from activity class or anywhere else to this Class you must send as parameter in Execute method. like :

```
boperation.execute(a1);
```

second value used for `onProgressUpdate()` method, that you can show progress to User.

third value used for `onPostExecute()` that you want intract with `UI` thread after some work.

now, if you want send method to onPostExecute() you need do that in `doInBackground` method with return value, like:

```
@Override
protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getstocks="Select " + st.column1 + " as _id, " + st.column3 + " From "+ st.tablename;
            a1=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(getstocks, null);


            return YourCursor;
        }
```

and in onPostExecute() method you must have something like:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            if(a1.moveToNext())
            {
                displaystocks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            final poplist populatestocks=new poplist(getApplicationContext(),a1) ;
            popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);
        }
```

so if you don't want send anything to your asyncTask class you must call

```
 new boperation.execute();
```

or you can create one object and call execute method like:

```
boperation object = new boperation();
object.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks @Shayan your explanation is helpful for me.. I have changed code accordingly.